# How to setup unit tests for a controller with nested attributed in Rails with Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I have a `person` model that is the base for all types of users in my Rails 4 app. I have an `administrator` model, a `worker` model, a `client` model that all accept nested attributes. Here's my `administrator` model

```
class Administrator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person

  ... other model code here
end
```

In my SQLite database I have a constraint that says `person_id` cannot be null.

The controller test for the `administrator` is failing with the message'

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL 
constraint failed: administrators.person_id: INSERT INTO "administrators"
("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)
```

`administrators_controller_test.rb` contains the following,

```
setup do
  @administrator = administrators(:administrator_montgomery_burns)
  @person = people(:person_montgomery_burns)
end

test "should create administrator" do
  assert_difference('Administrator.count') do
    post :create,
      administrator: {
        person_id: @administrator.person_id
      }
  end
  assert_redirected_to administrator_path(assigns(:administrator))
end
```

I've also tried,

```
test "should create administrator" do
  assert_difference('Administrator.count') do
    post :create,
      administrator: {
        person: {
          first_name: @person.first_name,
          ... all other person attributes
        }
      }
  end

  assert_redirected_to administrator_path(assigns(:administrator))
end
```

Any ideas how this should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. I had a look at the log file `params` hash in the controller in development mode, (where it is working), and in test mode, (where it isn't). Instead of

```
test "should create administrator" do
  assert_difference('Administrator.count') do
    post :create,
      administrator: {
        person: {
          first_name: @person.first_name,
          ... all other person attributes
        }
      }
  end

  assert_redirected_to administrator_path(assigns(:administrator))
end
```

use

```
test "should create administrator" do
  assert_difference('Administrator.count') do
    post :create,
      administrator: {
        person_attributes: {
          first_name: @person.first_name,
          ... all other person attributes
        }
      }
  end

  assert_redirected_to administrator_path(assigns(:administrator))
end
```

Just change `person:` to `person_attributes:`.